# Extracting additional data with query with keen.io

Tags: keen-io

I have a (simplified) query that looks as follows.

```
var pageViews = new Keen.Query('count', {
    eventCollection: 'Loaded a Page',
    groupBy: 'company.id'
});
```

And use it as follows.

```
client.run(pageViews, function(result, error) {
    // Do something here
});
```

This will give me the following JSON to work with:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "company.id": 1,
      "result": 3
    },
    {
      "company.id": 2,
      "result": 11
    },
    {
      "company.id": 3,
      "result": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I would also like to get back the name of each company, i.e. the `company.name` property. I looked through keen.io's documentation, and I could find no way of doing this. Is there a way to do this? Logically speaking, I don't see any reason why it would not be possible, but the question is if it has been implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grouping by multiple properties](https://keen.io/docs/api/#grouping-by-multiple-properties) will get you what you're looking for:

```
var pageViews = new Keen.Query('count', {
    eventCollection: 'Loaded a Page',
    groupBy: ['company.id','company.name']
});
```

That being said, it's important to note that Keen is not an entity database. Keen is optimized to store and analyze event data, [which is different than entity data](https://keen.io/blog/53958349217/analytics-for-hackers-how-to-think-about-event-data). More complex uses of entity data may not perform well using this solution.